# What is the most efficient way to merge multiple excel sheets in python?

Tags: openpyxl

I want to merge data from multiple huge excel files (100s of files, 100s of colums and 1000s of rows). The requirement is straight forward, I need to just copy and past data from all file in one large files.

I am using openpyxl library to achieve the task. It is working fine, the issue is, since, I am copying data cell by cell that is taking a lot of time (more than 30 minutes for some large files).

Is there any python library that can copy a range of data from one excel sheet to other, or if we can do the same task more efficiently using  openpyxl library?

Here is my current code:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import rmtree
import argparse
import os


// To parse command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( description = 'Merge excle (xls, xlsx files)')
parser.add_argument('main_file',help='Main excle file full path with file name', nargs='?',  default='./files/1.xlsx')
parser.add_argument('target_dir', help='Directory containg excel files to be merged with the main file', nargs='?', default='./files')
args = parser.parse_args()

//main file, in which all other xls or xlsx files will be merged
main_file = Path(args.main_file)
target_dir = Path(args.target_dir)


wb_main = load_workbook(main_file)
ws_main = wb_main.active

//Load all xls/xlsx files from the target directory and merge its contents in the main file
for file in target_dir.iterdir():

    if file.suffix == '.xls' or file.suffix == '.xlsx':
        if file.name != main_file.name:
            
            
             wb = load_workbook(file)
             ws = wb.active

             current_row = ws_main.max_row
             current_col = 0

             count = 0


             for row in ws.values:
                count += 1


                if current_row < ws_main.max_row + ws.max_row:
                    current_col = 0
                    current_row += 1
    
                for value in row:
                    if current_col < ws.max_column:
                        current_col += 1
                    ws_main.cell (current_row, current_col).value = value

//To save the final data in the main file
wb_main.save(main_file)
```

Comment: `if file.suffix == '.xls'` seems incorrect, Openpyxl wont load a '.xls' file. Have you read the Openpyxl documentation on optimisation and read_only mode?

Comment: @moken, Thanks for the feedback, let me check the documentation for read_only as well